# Unwanted Bluetooth sharing window appears when opening the containing directory of a download in Firefox. How do I fix this?

Tags: firefox, manjaro, thunar

Whenever I want to browse the location of a file I downloaded in Firefox a Bluetooth sharing application window appears instead. This is the same window that appears when I right click a local file in `Thunar` (Xfce's default file manager) and select *Send to* > *Bluetooth device*. This said I have no issues whatsoever when I browse directories in Thunar.

I have Firefox 47.0.1, which is running under Manjaro 16. I have checked the Application tab in Firefox settings but can see nothing that relates to directories or Bluetooth. I have seen no hint in `about:config` either.

How can I fix this wrong behaviour and have `Thunar` opened instead?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found: I opened MIME Type Editor in Xfce and scrolled down until I found `inode/directory`. In the third column was specified the bluetooth application. I just clicked the item in the third column then `Reset to defaults` in the popup menu. Now Thunar (instead of the bluetooth applet) opens directories.